# How can I see a Web API bearer token before it's returned?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, bearer-token

I have my own OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, but it looks like there's no place to hook into to see the generated bearer token after it's generated.

Is there a way to grab the to-be-returned token before it's returned? (hack or not)

Here's my setup:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decompiling, grabbing OAuth source from http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/, and upgrading my NuGet packages to the latest Owin implementation, I can now override a new method in my SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
    {
        string token = context.AccessToken;
        return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
    }
```

The above will give the ResponseContext to be returned, which contains everything I need:  enctypted token, user identity, claims...

This is a new method in the IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider interface as of NuGet package 3 (I believe)